# In the code the variable won't update

Tags: javascript, function, variables, setinterval, var

In the code the variable `memecount` won't update. Here is my code:

```
var memecount = 0;
var pepe = 1;
var pepemps = pepe*1
function timer1() {
    memecount = memecount + pepemps;
}
setInterval(timer1, 5000);
```

Comment: What do you want it to do ? Just put a `console.log` inside the `timer1` function, and you will see the values changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not actually changing the values of `memecount` and `pepemps` anywhere, so it makes sense that their sum (`memecount = memecount + pepemps`) would not change. Perhaps you meant to increment `pepe` inside the timer?

Comment: Omg... Wow... I completely missed that. Thanks mate. Cheers.